# com.exasol.jdbc.EXAResultSet cannot be cast to com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: mysql, jdbc, exasol

I am trying to build a DatabaseTable (my custom object) object by querying using jdbc DatabaseMetadata and ResultSet.

Below code works perfectly fine if I run it against MySQL database, but it fails with exception when tried against Exasol database.

```
 private DatabaseTableColumnMetadata getTableAndColumnNames(DatabaseMetaData metaData)
        throws SQLException {
        ResultSet tables = metaData.getTables(null,null,"%",null);
        while (tables.next()){
            if (tables.getString("TABLE_TYPE").equalsIgnoreCase("TABLE")
                && ((ResultSetImpl) tables).getConnection().getCatalog()
                .equals(tables.getString("TABLE_CAT"))) {

                     DatabaseTable table = DatabaseTable.builder().name(tables.getString("TABLE_NAME")).schema(tables.getString("TYPE_SCHEM")).build();
             }
        }
}
```

Exception thrown is as below

```
com.exasol.jdbc.EXAResultSet cannot be cast to com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl","message":"com.exasol.jdbc.EXAResultSet cannot be cast to com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl","name":"java.lang.ClassCastException
```

The exception thrown is at line where its trying to cast ***tables*** object to ***ResultSetImpl***.

I have both jars in my project exajdbc.jar as well as mysql-connector.jar

Any help or clue to solve this problem pls.

Comment: Maybe instead of doing this filtering, you should pass the catalog as the appropriate parameter to [`getTables(String catalog, String schemaPattern, String tableNamePattern, String[] types)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String[]))

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you've written this expression:

```
     ((ResultSetImpl) tables).getConnection().getCatalog()
```

In this expression you are casting `tables` to a MySQL-specific result-set implementation class, just so that you can get access to its `getConnection()` method.  It's perhaps not surprising you're getting an error attempting to use this code to read data from an Exasol database, because in this situation `tables` will be an Exasol-specific result-set implementation class.

Surely this result set comes from the same database connection as the `DatabaseMetaData` object that gets passed into your method?  I would expect the `getConnection()` method of the `DatabaseMetaData` object to return the same connection.

Try replacing the expression above with the following:

```
     metaData.getConnection().getCatalog()
```